# Android Notification Bar shows both icons - small and large one

Tags: java, android, layout, notifications

I'm creating android notification according to [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). I have a small icon for Status bar and a large icon for Notification bar.

However, in my case, the small icon is showing on both status bar and notification bar. 
How can I show different icons for status bar and notification drawer?

I have read something about a custom layout for the notification, but I don´t know how to set it up to match my conditions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Improved readability, added a link to the android notification dev documentaiton

Comment: Can you please post (some of) your code? Also, the documentation refers to a "notification area" in the status bar and a notification drawer. Can you please make sure the terminology is correct?